# Create a combination of "relative" and "grouped" chart in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I need to create a combination of "relative" and "grouped" chart in plotly.

I figured out how to create stacked and grouped by using this code:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go
import plotly

pyplt = plotly.offline.plot

data = {
    "Sports_19": [15, 23, 32, 10, 23, 22, 32, 24],
    "Casual_19": [4, 12, 11, 14, 15, 12, 22, 14],
    "Yoga_19": [4, 8, 18, 6, 12, 11, 10, 4],
    "Sports_20": [11, 18, 18, 0, 20, 12, 12, 11],
    "Casual_20": [20, 10, 9, 6, 10, 11, 17, 22],
    "Yoga_20": [11, 18, 18, 0, 20, 12, 12, 11],
    "labels": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 'June', 'July', "August"]
    
}

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Sports",x=data["labels"],y=data["Sports_19"],offsetgroup=19,marker_color='lightsalmon',text=data["Sports_19"],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Casual",x=data['labels'],y=data['Casual_19'],offsetgroup=19,base=data['Sports_19'],marker_color='crimson',text=data["Casual_19"],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Yoga",x=data['labels'],y=data['Yoga_19'],marker_color='indianred',text=data["Yoga_19"],textposition='auto',offsetgroup=19,base=[val1 + val2 for val1, val2 in zip(data["Sports_19"], data["Casual_19"])]))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Sports_20",x=data["labels"],y=data["Sports_20"],offsetgroup=20,marker_color='lightsalmon',showlegend=False,text=data["Sports_20"],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Casual_20",x=data['labels'],y=data['Casual_20'],offsetgroup=20,base=data['Sports_20'],marker_color='crimson',showlegend=False,text=data["Casual_20"],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Yoga_20", x=data['labels'], y=data['Yoga_20'], marker_color='indianred', text=data["Yoga_20"], showlegend=False, textposition='auto', offsetgroup=20, base=[val1 + val2 for val1, val2 in zip(data["Sports_20"], data["Casual_20"])]))

fig.update_layout(title="2019 vs 2020 Sales by Category",yaxis_title="Sales amount in US$")

fig.show()
pyplt(fig, auto_open=True)
```

Output is this:
[image]

Is there is any way i can convert this graph to combination of "relative" and "grouped"? May be not with plotly, but with matplotlib or another tools?

p.s. Here is the example of "relative graph"(but its not grouped):
[image]

Comment: Sorry but on what basis do you need to combine both charts?

Comment: i want to see the comparison between the sales share of every category in past two years

Comment: Your first image doesn't solves your purpose?? It compares both years right?

Comment: In first image is sales amount, i need the percentage, the share of every category in every month of the year.

Comment: The second graph is just random example from google pics, to explain what i mean by saying "relative" graph

Comment: It seems like you should be able to transform your data from absolute values to percentages, then plot using mostly the same logic? I'll try to post an answer

Comment: @Derek O Yes, you get it right. I need to transform the date from absolute values to percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way is to create two new dataframes `df_perc_19` and `df_perc_20` to store your data, normalized to relative percentages for each month in each year, rounding off to two digits using `.round(2)` since a long decimal will cause the default direction of the text to change - feel free to adjust this however you like.

Then access the values in these new dataframes for your traces, and although it's ugly, you can get percentages to display for the `text` parameter using something like: `text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_19["Casual_19"]]`

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
from plotly import graph_objects as go

# pyplt = plotly.offline.plot

data = {
    "Sports_19": [15, 23, 32, 10, 23, 22, 32, 24],
    "Casual_19": [4, 12, 11, 14, 15, 12, 22, 14],
    "Yoga_19": [4, 8, 18, 6, 12, 11, 10, 4],
    "Sports_20": [11, 18, 18, 0, 20, 12, 12, 11],
    "Casual_20": [20, 10, 9, 6, 10, 11, 17, 22],
    "Yoga_20": [11, 18, 18, 0, 20, 12, 12, 11],
    # "labels": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 'June', 'July', "August"]
    
}

labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 'June', 'July', "August"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index=labels)
## normalize data for the months of 2019, and the months of 2020
df_perc_19 = df.apply(lambda x: 100*x[["Sports_19","Casual_19","Yoga_19"]] / x[["Sports_19","Casual_19","Yoga_19"]].sum(),axis=1).round(2)
df_perc_20 = df.apply(lambda x: 100*x[["Sports_20","Casual_20","Yoga_20"]] / x[["Sports_20","Casual_20","Yoga_20"]].sum(),axis=1).round(2)

fig = go.Figure()
## traces for 2019
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Sports",x=labels,y=df_perc_19["Sports_19"],offsetgroup=19,marker_color='lightsalmon',text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_19["Sports_19"]],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Casual",x=labels,y=df_perc_19['Casual_19'],offsetgroup=19,base=df_perc_19['Sports_19'],marker_color='crimson',text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_19["Casual_19"]],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Yoga",x=labels,y=df_perc_19['Yoga_19'],marker_color='indianred',text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_19["Yoga_19"]],textposition='auto',offsetgroup=19,base=[val1 + val2 for val1, val2 in zip(df_perc_19["Sports_19"], df_perc_19["Casual_19"])]))
## traces for 2020
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Sports_20",x=labels,y=df_perc_20["Sports_20"],offsetgroup=20,marker_color='lightsalmon',showlegend=False,text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_20["Sports_20"]] ,textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Casual_20",x=labels,y=df_perc_20['Casual_20'],offsetgroup=20,base=df_perc_20['Sports_20'],marker_color='crimson',showlegend=False,text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_20["Casual_20"]],textposition='auto'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(name="Yoga_20", x=labels, y=df_perc_20['Yoga_20'], marker_color='indianred', text=[str(x)+"%" for x in df_perc_20["Yoga_20"]], showlegend=False, textposition='auto', offsetgroup=20, base=[val1 + val2 for val1, val2 in zip(df_perc_20["Sports_20"], df_perc_20["Casual_20"])]))

fig.update_layout(title="2019 vs 2020 Sales by Category",yaxis_title="Sales amount in US$ (percentage)")

fig.show()
# pyplt(fig, auto_open=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this concept works perfectly! Very smart way to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to hear the approach worked well for you!