# How to plot a % stacked bar plot with a given specific data structure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Feature1", "Target"], 
                  data=[["A", 0],
                        ["A", 1],
                        ["A", 2],
                        ["B", 0],
                        ["B", 1],
                        ["C", 1],
                        ["C", 2],
                        ["D", 1],
                        ["E", 0],
                        ["E", 2],
                        ["E", 2]])
```

How do I plot a % stacked bar plot with the given dataframe above, so that it will look something like the % stacked bar plot below (note: the proportions in the dataframe above is different to the proportion shown in the % stacked bar plot below)

[image: per_stacked_bar]

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I know the proportions are different, hence I had mentioned "...will look something like..."

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63774034/12870513

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a combination of "relative" and "grouped" chart in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772597/create-a-combination-of-relative-and-grouped-chart-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using your input for the a quick example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Feature1", "Target"], 
                  data=[["A", 0.0],
                        ["A", 1.0],
                        ["A", 2.0],
                        ["B", 0.0],
                        ["B", 1.0],
                        ["C", 1.0],
                        ["C", 2.0],
                        ["D", 1.0],
                        ["E", 0.0],
                        ["E", 2.0],
                        ["E", 2.0]])
```

#### Then you can pivot the data to get it in a format that will plot as intended.

```
pivot_df = df.pivot(columns='Feature1', values = "Target")
pivot_df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(12,6), legend=False)
```

From here there are many things you could do to change the colors, label the axes, adding a legend, etc.

[image]

If you wanted to use percentages you could just calculate another columns that has the percent of each value.  You could get a new columns called percent by using:

```
df["Percent"] = df.groupby("Feature1").apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff Coldplume, I have changed slightly what I wanted to do and I couldn't figure it out on how to do this. Would you be able to see and help. The question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63822257/percentage-stacked-bar-chart-with-a-specific-data-structure