# Percentage stacked bar chart with a specific data structure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following specific data structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Feature1", "Target"], 
                  data=[["A", 0],
                        ["A", 0],
                        ["A", 0],
                        ["A", 1],
                        ["A", 1],
                        ["A", 1], 
                        
                        ["B", 1],
                        ["B", 1],
                        ["B", 0],
                        ["B", 0],
                        ["B", 0]])
```

How do I plot a percentage stacked bar chart which looks something like the below, so that I can show the proportions of 0's and 1's in the two groups A and B?

[image: perc_bar]

Note: the proportions in the dataframe `df` are different to the ones shown in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first count the values of each type, then divide by the total for each feature and multiply by 100.

The resulting dataframe can be plotted as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Feature1", "Target"],
                  data=[["A", 0], ["A", 0], ["A", 0], ["A", 1], ["A", 1], ["A", 1],
                        ["B", 1], ["B", 1], ["B", 0], ["B", 0], ["B", 0]])
df1 = (df.groupby(["Feature1", "Target"]).size() / df.groupby(["Feature1"]).size() * 100)
df1 = df1.reset_index(name='Percentage')
features = np.unique(df1['Feature1'])
plt.bar(x=features, height=100, color='dodgerblue', label='Target = 1')
plt.bar(x=features,
        height=[df1[(df1['Feature1'] == x) & (df1['Target'] == 0)]['Percentage'].values[0] for x in features],
        color='crimson', label='Target = 0')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Feature1')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]